Error "Unable to parse" Custom Data Flow Template
I am trying to create custom data flow template for JDBC connection however when importing the template (python code to json converted) it is giving error/warning in console.
Error/Warning:Fail to process as Flex Template and Legacy Template. Flex Template Process result:No SDK language information is provided., Legacy Template Process result:Unable to parse template file 

custom_template_code:
{
  "name": "Oracle_to_gcs_metadata",
  "description": "A pipeline which loads data from Oracle to GCS as Parquet files",
  "streaming": false,
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "jdbcConnectionUrl",
      "label": "JDBC Connection URL String",
      "helpText": "The JDBC connection URL to connect to the Oracle database (e.g., jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname:port/service_name)",
      "regexes": [
        "^jdbc:oracle:thin:@\\/\\/[^\\n\\r]+$"
      ],
      "paramType": "TEXT"
    },
    {
      "name": "jdbcUsername",
      "label": "JDBC Connection User Name",
      "helpText": "The username for the JDBC connection",
      "paramType": "TEXT"
    },
    {
      "name": "jdbcPassword",
      "label": "JDBC Connection Password",
      "helpText": "The password for the JDBC connection",
      "paramType": "PASSWORD"
    },
    {
      "name": "jdbcSourceQuery",
      "label": "JDBC Source SQL Query",
      "helpText": "The SQL query to execute on the Oracle database (e.g., SELECT * FROM table_name)",
      "paramType": "TEXT"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputGcsLocation",
      "label": "Output GCS Location",
      "helpText": "The GCS location where the output Parquet files will be saved (e.g., gs://bucket-name/output-directory/)",
      "regexes": [
        "^gs:\\/\\/[^\\n\\r]+$"
      ],
      "paramType": "TEXT"
    }
  ]
}

Python Code:
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, SetupOptions
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.io.parquetio import WriteToParquet

class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--jdbcConnectionUrl', type=str, help='JDBC Connection URL String')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--jdbcUsername', type=str, help='JDBC Connection User Name')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--jdbcPassword', type=str, help='JDBC Connection Password')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--jdbcSourceQuery', type=str, help='JDBC Source SQL Query')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--outputGcsLocation', type=str, help='GCS Location for Output Parquet Files')

class ConstructJdbcUrl(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, jdbcConnectionUrl):
        yield f"jdbc:oracle:thin:@{jdbcConnectionUrl.get()}"

class ReadFromJdbcAndWriteToGCS(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, custom_options):
        jdbc_url = f"jdbc:oracle:thin:@{custom_options.jdbcConnectionUrl.get()}"
        query = custom_options.jdbcSourceQuery.get()
        username = custom_options.jdbcUsername.get()
        password = custom_options.jdbcPassword.get()
        output_gcs_location = custom_options.outputGcsLocation.get()

        # Read from JDBC
        with beam.Pipeline() as p:
            jdbc_data = (p
                         | 'Read from JDBC' >> ReadFromJdbc(
                             fetch_size=None,
                             table_name="ACCOUNTS",
                             driver_class_name='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
                             jdbc_url=jdbc_url,
                             username=username,
                             password=password,
                             query=query
                         ))

            # Write to GCS as Parquet files
            (jdbc_data
             | 'Write to GCS as Parquet' >> WriteToParquet(
                 file_path_prefix=output_gcs_location,
                 schema=None
             ))

def run(argv=None):
    # Define your pipeline options
    options = PipelineOptions(argv)
    custom_options = options.view_as(CustomOptions)
        
    # Enable saving of the main session state for any global imports.
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)

    # Create a PCollection with a single element to pass around
    jdbc_url_pcoll = (p
                      | 'Create Empty' >> beam.Create([None]))

    # Read from JDBC and write to GCS
    _ = (jdbc_url_pcoll
         | 'ReadFromJdbcAndWriteToGCS' >> beam.ParDo(ReadFromJdbcAndWriteToGCS(), custom_options))

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()

Deployment Command:
python oracle-to-gcs.py --runner DataflowRunner --no_use_public_ips --subnetwork <> --staging_location <> --temp_location <> --project $DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID --job_name oracle-to-gcs --region us-east4 --template_location gs://$DEVSHELL_PROJECT_ID-templates/templates/oracle_to_gcs --experiment=use_beam_bq_sink

Generally when importing custom template it should load the input values in the console Although its not happening.
